# Using Python 2.7 in Anaconda 3

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I am using Anaconda Navigator for Python 3 to create jupyter notebooks.  I created a custom python 2.7 environment. When I ran an old notebook of mine written for python 2.7, I got the "print statement is missing parentheses" error, suggesting it is interpreting my code in python 3, not 2, as intended.

How do I get it to run python 2.7?[image]

Comment: The kernel shows Python 3.  No other kernels are available.

Comment: You need to install `ipykernel` into your Python 2 environment and change the kernel of the Notebook